# Spring Hibernate Connection Timeout

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, integration

I am using spring & hibernate in my java application. I provided all connection parameters but I am getting following error which says that connection timed out

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring-bean.xml]; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.motive.nbn.alu.queuemanager.TTLMonitor.testApp.main(testApp.java:25)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:411)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:525)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:208)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:291)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:310)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:987)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:923)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:841)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:676)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1314)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1281)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:283)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1191)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1000)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:232)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 14 more
```

Here is my spring-bean.xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean name="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass"
            value="com.motive.nbn.alu.queuemanager.TTLMonitor.Executor" />
        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="timeout" value="5" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetail" />
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="5" />
        <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />
        <property name="misfireInstructionName" value="MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW" />
    </bean>
   <bean id="taskExecutor"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="threadCount" value="5" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="executor" class="com.motive.nbn.alu.queuemanager.TTLMonitor.Executor">
        <constructor-arg ref="taskExecutor" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="applicationContextProvider"
        class="com.motive.nbn.alu.queuemanager.TTLMonitor.ApplicationContextProvider" />
    <!-- Hibernate related -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@<Actual_URL>:1521:system" />
        <property name="username" value="<actual_username>" />
        <property name="password" value="<actual_password>" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key=”hibernate.show_sql”>false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">DEFAULT_SCHEMA_NAME</prop>
                <prop key=”hibernate.current_session_context_class”>thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I am successfully able to connect to database using any IDE (SQLEditor etc). 
To play around with it I tried following

1. From spring-bean.xml, I removed all connection properties & keep it blank. Result: I got the same exception.
2. in spring-bean.xml I configure to read from properties files. But I got the same exception

In all cases I am getting same exception.

I try to print the logs using log4j but nothing is shown in logs. My first doubt is that it is because of connection parameters. But I can't find a way to track whi`enter code here`ch connection parameters are actually used by Spring to create connection.

Comment: Are you sure this is the only configured spring Datasource? What happens when you remove the bean?

Comment: I suggest you progressively remove beans in order to help you pinpoint the problematic one

Comment: Thanks Eric, As we have more than one engineer working on same code base so we had included different datasource as well which has invalid connection parameters. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I guess you resolved the problem but to me it looks like you have an issue finding the XSD of one of the xmlns definitions.